# javascript regex get different answer with same expression in Chrome console

Tags: javascript

I want to test Javascript Regex in Chrome Console. However, I get different answers with the same expression (refer to the picture). If I use original literal to test, the I can get right answer. What is the reason for that?

```js
re = /^[a-z][0-9a-z]*$/g;
console.log(re.test("a34"));
console.log(re.test("a34"));
console.log(re.test("a34"));
console.log(re.test("a34"));
console.log(/^[a-z][0-9a-z]*$/g.test("a23"));
console.log(/^[a-z][0-9a-z]*$/g.test("a23"));
```

Comment: Also, I highly suggest simply reading the documentation, which clearly explains this behavior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry for the image uploaded. I have removed the image and use code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> Use test() whenever you want to know whether a pattern is found in a string. test() returns a boolean, unlike the String.prototype.search() method, which returns the index (or -1 if not found). To get more information (but with slower execution), use the exec() method (similar to the String.prototype.match() method). As with exec() (or in combination with it), **test() called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.**